# Splitting Doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering if I could get any insight as to why I get the error: `terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: coordinates (400,0) outside valid range of [0, 399] X [0, 239]` when I run the following code.

The method is suppose to split the DLL at the index passed to it. So `split(2)` would leave the list it was called on with 2 nodes, while the rest of the old list would be returned as new list. I've tried many different ways to write this and none of them work (we must use unique_ptrs for the assignment).

```
template <class T>
auto dl_list<T>::split(node* start, unsigned split_point)
    -> std::unique_ptr<node>
{
    assert(split_point > 0);
    if(start == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    node* curr = start;
    uint64_t i = 0;
    while(i < split_point)
    {
    curr = (curr->next).get();
    i++;
   }
    std::unique_ptr<node> temp{nullptr};
    temp = std::move(curr->prev->next);
    (temp)->prev = nullptr;
    return temp;
}
```

Here is the wrapper method, if that helps:

```
template <class T>
auto dl_list<T>::split(unsigned split_point) -> dl_list
{
if (split_point >= size_)
    return {};

if (split_point == 0)
{
    dl_list lst;
    swap(*this);
    return lst;
}

auto old_size = size_;
auto new_head = split(head_.get(), split_point);

// set up current list
size_ = split_point;
for (tail_ = head_.get(); tail_->next; tail_ = tail_->next.get())
    ;

// set up returned list
dl_list ret;
ret.head_ = std::move(new_head);
for (ret.tail_ = ret.head_.get(); ret.tail_->next;
     ret.tail_ = ret.tail_->next.get())
    ;
ret.size_ = old_size - split_point;
return ret;
}
```

Comment: Finally a teacher that encourages `std::unique_ptr` and moves. What is this, 2050? The error you show does not seem to be directly related to the code you posted, by the way.

Comment: As much as unique pointers are a great thing, they're probably misplaced inside a doubly linked list node... The node should be private to the list, I suppose.

Comment: I was told that this meant that one of the 2 lists was then the wrong size after the call (which caused a problem in the underlying images that were modified based on the split of the 2 lists). But you're saying this code would result in the first list being of size 2 for a call of split(start,2) and the remainder of the original list would be in a new list accessible by the returned temp?

Comment: before updating `temp->prev` you should update `temp->prev->next`. using `std::move` doesn't do any magic.

Comment: Where's your logic for if the split_point requested is greater than the size of the list?

Comment: It is handled in the wrapper method we were provided. And how would I update temp->prev->next? I can't just assign nullptr to it since it's a unique_ptr, and I don't see any methods for changing it. The reset or release method maybe?

Comment: @user3424684: sorry, i didn't believe they were `unique_ptr`. with the single ownership smart pointer it's cleared. it is really advanced teacher who gives assignment to learn about how ungood ownership smart pointers are for non-owning references.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s code to unlink a specified node plus rest of list, on the node’s left (prev) side, assuming that there always is a previous node (i.e. a list with header node):

```
auto unlinked_list_from( Node* p )
    -> Node*
{
    p->prev->next = nullptr;
    p->prev = nullptr;
    return p;
}
```

Finding the *n*’th node is a separate problem.

Combining the two, in finding the *n*’th node and unlinking it and the rest of the list, is a higher level problem where you use the two lower level solutions.

---

It’s generally *not a good idea* to user ownership smart-pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` in the internal pointers of linked list or tree. It’s simply not the case that each node owns the previous and next node, in the sense of having responsibility for destruction. This is one situation where raw pointers rule.

But instead, except for learning and for advanced programming, use standard library containers such as `std::vector`.

Comment: Isn't that basically what I am doing above? Except that we need to return a unique_ptr to the new head, not a node. Am I wrong in assuming that the move statement empties curr->prev->next after moving it to temP?

Comment: Also, we have no choice in the matter. The skeleton of the class was written for us using unique_ptr

Comment: @user3424684: it depends on how the `prev` and `next` are declared. if they're `std::unique_ptr` then yes it clears. but it's not a good idea to have such ownership, so that basic a priori assumption is that they're raw pointers.